# Regular Expression: match everything up to an optional capture group

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
(.*)(?:([\+\-\*\/])(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))
```

the intention is to capture mathematical expressions in the form (left expression) (operator) (right operand), e.g. `1+2+3` would be captured as `(1+2)(+)(3)`.  It will also handle single operands, e.g. `1+2` would be captured as (1)(+)(2).

The problem I am having is that this regular expression won't match on a single operand with no operator, e.g. 5 should be matched in the first capture group with nothing in the second and third (5)()(). If I make the last part optional:

```
(.*)(?:([\+\-\*\/])(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?
```

then the initial group will always capture the entire expression. Is there any way I can make the second part optional but have it take precedence over the greedy matching done by the first group?

Comment: Why not use a parser?

Comment: Did you try *lazy* matching? [`(.+?)(?:([-+*\/])(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?`](https://regex101.com/r/rS0yX6/2)

Comment: Making the first group lazy match does not work, I can't fully explain the results I get if I do that, but it is not what I want.

Comment: Then please show the string you have that does cannot be matched with lazy matching.

Comment: 1+2+3+4 does not work.

Comment: Still unclear, are you trying to get *repeated groups* with Java regex? It is impossible. Just use splitting or a `\G` based regex with multiple matching (e.g. [`\G([-+*\/])?(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/uC1aN6/1)).

Comment: No, I just want to match everything up to the last operator and operand, but I want that part to be optional so that it also matches a single number. There should be only 3 groups normally containing (left expression)(operator)(right operand) but could also be (single digit)(empty)(empty). It is also possible that left expression is a simple operand too.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: https://regex101.com/r/oH7aN9/1 (or with `$` in place of the lookahead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This Regex will:

- captures the math expression upto the last operation
- captures the last operation
- captures the last number in the math expression
- assumes that each number might have a plus or minus sign showing that the number is positive or negative
- assumes each number might be non-integer
- assumes the math expression can contain any number of operations such as: `1+2` or `1+2+3` or `1+2+3+4` or `1+2+3+4...`
- validates the string is a math expression. There are some edge cases which are not accounted for here such as the use of parenthesis, or other complex math symbols.

**Raw Regular Expression**

Note this being Java, you'll need to escape the back slashes in this regex. To escape them simply replace all the `\` with a `\\`.

`^(?=(?:[-+*/^]?[-+]?\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)*$)([-+]?[0-9.]+$|[-+]?[0-9.]+(?:[-+*/^][-+]?[0-9.]+)*(?=[-+*/^]))(?:([-+*/^])([-+]?[0-9.]+))?$`

## Explanation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Overview**

In this expression I'm first validating that the string is composed of only operations `-+/*^`, optional signs `-+`, and integer or noninteger numbers. Since was already validated the rest of the expression can simply refer to numbers as `[0-9.]+`, which improves the readability.

**Capture Groups**

0 Gets the entire string
1 Gets the entire string upto but not including the last operation, if there are no operations then group 1 will have the entire string
2 Gets the last operation, if it exists
3 Gets the number and sign after the last operation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+*/^]?                 any character of: '-', '+', '*', '/',
                               '^' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [.]                      any character of: '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+*/^]                  any character of: '-', '+', '*', '/',
                               '^'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+*/^]                  any character of: '-', '+', '*', '/',
                               '^'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+*/^]                  any character of: '-', '+', '*', '/',
                               '^'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-+]?                    any character of: '-', '+' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Examples

**Sample Text**

```
1+2+-3
```

**Sample Capture Groups**

```
[0] = 1+2+-3
[1] = 1+2
[2] = +
[3] = -3
```

Online demo: http://fiddle.re/b2w5wa

**Sample Text**

```
-3
```

**Sample Capture Groups**

```
[0] = -3
[1] = -3
[2] = 
[3] =
```

Online demo: http://fiddle.re/07kqra

**Sample Java Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^(?=(?:[-+*/^]?[-+]?\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)*$)([-+]?[0-9.]+$|[-+]?[0-9.]+(?:[-+*/^][-+]?[0-9.]+)*(?=[-+*/^]))(?:([-+*/^])([-+]?[0-9.]+))?$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't match on the case where the input is simply a single operand (e.g. single digit or decimal, positive or negative -3.1). In this case I was hoping to match this in capture group 1, and groups 2 and 3 would be empty. Any idea if this would be possible? I can easily do this in code by doing an extra step to check for a single operand first before extracting the rest, but it would be nice and clean to do it in one regex.

Comment: @DaveJohnston, sure. I've updated my answer to match your condition where an expression might only have a single item.

Comment: I find that with the change it stops extracting the anything into groups 2 and 3. It does match simple digits now, but everything gets matched into group 1.

Comment: Ugg, you're right. Ok I found and squashed the bug, in doing this I've made a wholesale change to the expression to improve readability and <cough>debugging</cough>. Sorry for the confusion.